# ASP MVC 6 RC1 Edit form creates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple Web application in ASP.NET MVC 6 RC1.

The problem is that when editing a previously added item. The item returned to the Edit POST has an ID = 0, so it creates a copy of the data I was trying to update.

When pressing the Edit link, it takes me to the correct route:

```
http://localhost:41250/Proyectos/Edit/1
```

And the GET IActionResult recieves the correct id.

But inside the edit form, when I press the Save button, in the Controller POST part of the Edit it recieves a proyecto who has all the data from the form except the id (ProyectoId) which is 0.

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RegistroHora.Models
{
    public class Proyecto
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Key]
        public int ProyectoId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Número de Horas")]
        public decimal NumHoras { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Horas")]
        public string TipoHoras { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Proyecto Finalizado")]
        public bool Concluido { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Registro> Registros { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model RegistroHora.Models.Proyecto

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Proyecto</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Nombre" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NumHoras" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="NumHoras" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumHoras" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TipoHoras" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="TipoHoras" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TipoHoras" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkboxs">
                    <input asp-for="Concluido" type="checkbox"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(i => i.Concluido)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using RegistroHora.Models;

namespace RegistroHora.Controllers
{
    public class ProyectosController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ProyectosController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: Proyectos
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Proyecto.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Proyectos/Details/5
        public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            Proyecto proyecto = _context.Proyecto.Single(m => m.ProyectoId == id);
            if (proyecto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(proyecto);
        }

        // GET: Proyectos/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Proyectos/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Proyecto proyecto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Proyecto.Add(proyecto);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(proyecto);
        }

        // GET: Proyectos/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            Proyecto proyecto = _context.Proyecto.Single(m => m.ProyectoId == id);
            if (proyecto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(proyecto);
        }

        // POST: Proyectos/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(Proyecto proyecto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Update(proyecto);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(proyecto);
        }

        // GET: Proyectos/Delete/5
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            Proyecto proyecto = _context.Proyecto.Single(m => m.ProyectoId == id);
            if (proyecto == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(proyecto);
        }

        // POST: Proyectos/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Proyecto proyecto = _context.Proyecto.Single(m => m.ProyectoId == id);
            _context.Proyecto.Remove(proyecto);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I have NO problem with Index, Create, Delete or Details, only Edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `ProyectoId` value from your form. You may keep that in a hidden field inside your form.

```
<form asp-action="Edit">

   <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProyectoId" />

   <!-- Your existing form fields for other properties goes here -->

   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

</form>
```

Comment: That worked. Is this a good practice? Or a work around? Because Previously I didn't need to do this for Edit to work.

Comment: **You must pass the Id from your form**. This is not a workaround. I am curious to know how it worked for you without it. May be you had the Id as part of the form action url  ?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to change signature for method Edit, like this:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Proyecto proyecto)
```

In this case, you can pass id over action URL. In this case you need to modify action URL in your view as:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id=@Model.ProyectoId>
```

Of cource, you need proper Route that support Id as parametar.

*P.s. Id you prefere the first approach, just remove **[ScaffoldColumn(false)]** from your property class.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the update in edit is around the key(ProyectoId); you cannot change it; however instead of making it will disappear by